# Parse an array with regular expression

Tags: regex

I have JS file and I need to parse that array in it:

```
something: ['Prefix.All','Ignore.Me','Prefix.Another']
```

I need to get all elements from "something" array with defined prefix. 
Now I can get it, if array will contain only one element. My regexp:

```
String: something: ['Prefix.All']
Can get element with:
/something\s*:\s*\[['"](Prefix[a-zA-Z0-9.]+)['"]]/
```

But how to find many elements in array? And how to find more than one "something" array in file?

Comment: Is your *something* always going to start with `Prefix.All`  I would suggest you to split it by `comma`...

Comment: I need to find "Prefix.***[.***]" here. Not Prefix.All

Comment: What regex engine are you using for this? Unless it's .NET, you can't do it with a single regex.

Comment: uh, take string, find first `[`, find last `]`. take substring in `[ ]`, split it by `,`. find all substrings, that have prefix `Prefix`. Why you think, that regexp can really helps you?

Comment: In that case I will find: required:[..], anything:[..], another:[..] e.t.c

Comment: uh, where is your smarty mind? 
Take string, filter it by containing `something:[...]` (you can do it by ever regexp). then do my algorithm above ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In PHP you need to do it in two steps (which is probably better anyway - cramming everything into a single regex isn't always the best idea).

First, match the array you're looking for. Note that this regex requires that there are no brackets between the delimiters `[` and `]`, so nested arrays or strings that contain brackets will cause the regex to fail (as in "match the wrong text"):

```
if (preg_match('/\bsomething: \[([^[\]]*)\]/', $subject, $regs)) {
    $result = $regs[1];
}
```

This will find the first occurrence of a string like `something: ['Prefix.All','Ignore.Me','Prefix.Another']` and put `'Prefix.All','Ignore.Me','Prefix.Another'` into `$result`.

Then you can get all the matches from that:

```
preg_match_all('/\bPrefix[^\']*/', $result, $final, PREG_PATTERN_ORDER);
$final = $final[0];
```

Answer (score 0):

In regex you can group a token with `()`, and ask for it many times with `*`.

So: `(something)*`would give you every instance of the word 'something'.

Further: `(__your__token__here__)*` finds every instance of your token.

Paste some of your array here: http://gskinner.com/RegExr/ and use the regex builder to test your regex

Does that help?

Comment: I tried simple example. Find create[\d] in that string: "create2 create3 create4". But ()* don't work. Here is my repexp: /(create[\d])*/ . It can't do that. Mistake?

Comment: See edit - I always use an online regex tester to test what I want to do until I get it right - without seeing your array its a bit hard to figure out what you are trying to achieve. For your example, you just need `(create[\d])`

Comment: `(something)*` matches `""`, `"something"`, `"somethingsomething"` etc., but it doesn't do at all what the OP wants.

Comment: Not really. In his example, two of the "tokens" he's looking for are separated by a token he does not want to match, so `*` wouldn't work.